# Load jQuery through Google API in Rails using HAML?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, jrails

This feels like it should be pretty simple, but not much seems to be loading.

I have this in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'
%script{ :type => "text/javascript", :charset => "utf-8" }
  //<![CDATA[
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2"); 
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
  //]]>
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

... where my `application.js` file contains some good 'ole jQuery.  I have installed [JRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) and my jQuery works fine with local copies of the libraries, but I want to use the ones from Goolge API.

Here's what my browser generates:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script charset='utf-8' type='text/javascript'>
  <!-- /<![CDATA[ -->
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
  <!-- /]]> -->
</script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1255040651" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm using Safari and the Error Console, which reports the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

Correspondingly, none of my jQuery scripts are working.

Help?

Comment: That HTML code this haml source generates?

Comment: No, none of this is generated code.

Comment: What is shown in browser? What html code if any?

Comment: Added the browser output and generated error message to my original post. Thoughts??

Comment: It's defently can't load http://www.google.com/jsapi.js file. Did you try to access this url in your browser?

Comment: I've tried your HTML code (without appication.js) in Chrome and FireFox. It works fine.

Comment: You can try some debug proxy (like Fiddler) or FireBug to see if this file (http://www.google.com/jsapi.js) is loaded at all.

Comment: Progress! If I change my initial tag from `= javascript_include_tag 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'` to `%script{ :src => 'http://www.google.com/jsapi', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8' }` it works.  You said it worked for you using the first method?

Comment: Huh, I thought it was supposed to escape those URLs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`javascript_include_tag` automatically puts a .js on the end. There seems to be no way round this while using `javascript_include_tag`. You should (as per your own comments) create your own script tag:

```
%script{ :src => 'google.com/jsapi', :type => 'text/javascript', :charset => 'utf-8' }
```

Personally I prefer to skip the jsapi, and reference the libraries directly, so just:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote about Haml, you can use the `:javascript` filter rather than defining a script tag with CDATA and content manually:

```
:javascript
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2"); 
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
```